# Can the global new operator be overridden based on allocated object's type traits?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I'm experimenting with upgrading our pooled fixed-block memory allocator to take advantage of C++11 type traits.

Currently it is possible to force any allocation of any object anywhere to be dispatched to the correct pool by overriding [the global new operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/)  in the traditional way, *eg*

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size) 
{ // if-cascade just for simplest possible example
   if ( size <= 64 ) { return g_BlockPool64.Allocate(); }
   else if ( size <= 256 ) { return g_BlockPool256.Allocate(); }
   // etc .. else assume arguendo that we know the following will work properly
   else return malloc(size);
}
```

In many cases we could improve performance further if objects could be dispatched to different pools depending on type traits such as `is_trivially_destructible`. **Is it possible to make a templatized global new operator that is aware of the allocated type, not just a requested size?** Something equivalent to

```
template<class T>
void *operator new( size_t size)
{
  if ( size < 64 ) 
  {  return std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value ? 
            g_BlockPool64_A.Allocate() : 
            g_BlockPool64_B.Allocate(); } //  etc
}
```

Overriding the member new operator in every class won't work here; we really need this to automatically work for any allocation anywhere. Placement new won't work either: requiring every alloc to look like

```
Foo *p = new (mempool<Foo>) Foo();
```

is too cumbersome and people will forget to use it.

Comment: Neat idea. Though how does being trivially destructible help the memory manager? The manager cares not about construction nor destruction.

Comment: @GManNickG If all trivially destructible objects go into the same pool, we can deallocate them en masse by just unmapping the memory page and not calling any destructors at all. It's one OS call instead of millions of deallocations. Useful when all allocations for a level chunk go into a block and you can just throw the thing overboard when leaving that area. There are already other mechanisms to prevent people from holding pointers into this block past their lifetime.

Comment: No.  Also, `return ::new(size);` is infinite recursion.

Comment: Sure, but that has to do with lifetime policies, not memory allocation. You can't just decide to free the memory block whenever, you have to wait for the lifetime of the objects living in that memory to end, no matter how trivial that destruction. And to do that, you have to decide at a single point in your application's code, "okay, this entire block can go (and the lifetimes of the objects residing there will be implicitly ended)". I don't know how a memory manager can decide if some trivially destructible objects belong to one group or another, so this code must reside outside of it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the usual way of doing this is by coding up an `arena_allocator` that is used explicitly in the application layer to group allocations together.

Comment: @GManNickG Basically, the new operator dispatches allocations to different pools based on other global state. Any allocation made *eg* while loading the desert level goes into the desert level's pool. When you leave the desert level, by definition every resource it allocated is past lifetime. We have got an explicit arena allocator with its own interface and Alloc() functions etc; I'm trying to see if I can use type_traits to let people just use `new` instead of having to ban it in the coding standards.

Comment: Check this:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DvgxYxrMH_v196YhPebAMaD7qMR3utTN4-ytVdZLPWE/edit#heading=h.j2yj7ppevde0
especially the two references in it

Comment: @Crashworks: "based on other global state" Cringe. :) Personally, I would leave things alone at the global allocation level, just let it do its job like it's supposed to at a generic level, and explicitly allocate things in arenas when it makes sense. It may require more typing, but it's certainly easier to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. The allocation/deallocation functions have the following signatures:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t);
void* operator new[](std::size_t);
void operator delete(void*);
void operator delete[](void*);
```

Most deviations from these signatures will result in your function not being used at all. In a typical implementation you're basically replacing the default implementations at the linker level -- i.e., the existing function has some particular mangled name. If you provide a function with a name that mangles to an identical result, it'll get linked instead. If your function doesn't mangle to the same name, it won't get linked.

A template like you've suggested might get used in some cases, but if so, it would lead to undefined behavior. Depending on how you arranged headers (for example) you could end up with code mixing the use of your template with the default functions, at which point about the best you could hope for would be that it crash quickly and cleanly.